# Samba: доступ к серверу по имени в другой подсети

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, openvpn, samba

### tl;dr

Как настроить доступ через samba клиент к серверу из другой подсети по имени?

### Описание конкретной ситуации

Есть гетерогенная сеть (Windows/Linux) (условно `192.168.0.0/24`) к ней подключён клиент по openVPN  (`10.8.0.0/24`). Маршруты между сетями настроены; по ip-адресам доступ к машинам подсети с клиента и обратно есть.

Теперь вопрос: как минимальной кровью настроить чтобы был доступ к серверам samba и win-рабочих станций по имени? Желательно, чтобы вся конфигурацию производить только на шлюзе (`192.168.0.4`; `10.8.0.1`, Linux Debian 9 "stretch", samba-4.5.12, openvpn-2.4.0).

Текущий конфиг на шлюзе (на машинах в основной сети аналогичные за исключением доступа по паролю и шар):

```
[global]
   workgroup = NETWORK_WG
   server string = %h server
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
   usershare max shares = 100

# Далее несколько шар
# ...
```

На клиенте за openVPN'ом (`10.8.0.2`) всё аналогично с другой workgroup'ой:

```
[global]
    workgroup = REMOTE_WG
    server string = Samba Server %v
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
    security = user
    guest ok = yes
    map to guest = bad user
# Шары
```

#### Update 1

nmbd отказывается слушать на tun-интерфейсе шлюза т.к. согласно логам

> not adding non-broadcast interface tun0

Конфиг openVPN'а:

```
port 61194
;proto tcp
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ca   /etc/openvpn/server/ovpn-root-key/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/ovpn-root-key/keys/goblin-server.crt
key  /etc/openvpn/server/ovpn-root-key/keys/goblin-server.key
dh   /etc/openvpn/server/ovpn-root-key/keys/dh4096.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/tmp/openvpn-ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0"
;client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
;cipher AES-256-GCM
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

#### Update 2

Поменял в openvpn'е устройство на `dev tap` — теперь шлюз виден по имени и со шлюза видна подсеть. Почему-то думал, что tap-устройство будет работать только с полноценным мостом. Оказалось — нет.

#### Update 3

Добавил в конфиг шлюза

```
wins support = yes
wins proxy = yes
domain master = yes # см. далее
```

Судя по всему это то что мне нужно. Давно об этом думал, но описание того, что делает `wins proxy` в man'е крайне непонятное.

Теперь из локальных хостов (в `192.168.0.3`[/24] ) на удалённый (`10.8.0.2`[/24]) можно достучаться по имени без какой-либо дополнительной конфигурации `smbclient`'ом, а также он отображается в `smbtree` и гуёвых просмоторщиках (последнего удалось стабильно добиться только с включением `domain master` и переноса всех в одну workgroup'у).

Добавил бы это всё ответом в ответ, но проблема в том, что обратный доступ (что в общем то основное) и обзор по имени почему-то не работают. Рабочая версия — почему-то локальные серверы не добавляются в WINS записи на гейтвее.

#### Update 4

Записи, которые выводит `nmbd` после убийства `SIGHUP`'ом полностью аналогичны для обеих подсетей, согласно wireshark'у запросы также аналогичны, но почему-то на запрос из `10.8.0.1/24` он отвечает, что адрес неизвестен, а на запрос из локальной сети выдаёт все адреса на которых слушает сервер... остаётся что проблема или в каких-то мудрёных настройках `nmbd`, или в баге...

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно помню, то Samba для одноранговых сетей и между разными сетями информация о именах не передаётся. Смотрите в сторону DNS и FTP.

Comment: Я почти уверен, что можно настроить nmbd как шлюз, который будет транслировать запросы на определение имени и широковещательные объявления себя между подсетями... пока меня смущает, что по имени недоступен даже сам шлюз... ЗЫ: при чём тут вообще FTP?

Comment: Если нужен доступ к файлам, то лучше использовать FTP. При необходимости, FTP-сервер можно открыть и для Интернета, что недоступно для Samba.

Comment: шуруп не всегда «лучше» гвоздя, а наоборот, как в данном случае, и подавно...